# I can't control / understand the flow of code

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

in longPressed function, I want it to complete the execution of `NSTimer` written in `initializeTimer()` and then go to `validate()`. But it doesn't seem to happen. Can someone please make understand my mistake, as I'm unable to get it right ... Output is given after code ....

And i also tried using fire() but it executes only once and I need it to keep on repeating it upon users need...
Thank you ....

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
      var choice:Int = 0
      var tim = NSTimer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()
        println("In ViewDidLoad")
        let longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer =  UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    }

    func longPressed(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
            if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){
                println("Long Pressed Begin")
                initializeTimer()
                validate(true, choice: choice)
           }
    }

    func initializeTimer(){
            println("In InitializeTimer")
            progressBar.setProgress(0, animated: true)
            tim = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: "setProgress", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    func validate(res: Bool, choice: Int){
            println("In validate ")
    }

    func setProgress(){
       println("In setProgress") 
       tim.invalidate()
    }
    }
```

Output :

In `ViewDidLoad`
`Long Pressed Begin`
In `InitializeTimer`
In `validate` 
in Set Progress

Comment: remove tim.invalidate() and call validate in setProgress() after completing your work.

Comment: Thanks johny kumar ... but actually i need to invalidate my timer first

Comment: if you invalidate your timer then it will not call method again.

Comment: Yes ..... that is the problem .

Comment: put a condition in setProgress when you want the timer to be invalidate. when condition willbe true then invalidate timer.

Comment: I did it .... i got solution ... Thanks for your help..

Comment: But my progressBar is not working smoothly

Comment: progressbar or searchbar?

Comment: you are calling progressBar.progress in setProgress() ?

Comment: +1 for your help johny ... that compel me to think .... Yes i'm calling progressBar.progress in setProgress()

Comment: do you have any suggestion for progressBar to work it smoothly

Comment: its range is in 0.0 to 1.0 check that you are increasing according to that convert your value of progress so that it comes within the range.

Comment: yes... i have managed the values for range ...